# What is the best method to get a non-student clinical rotation in the US?

Tags: medical-training

Medical students in the US usually participate in several clinical rotations before they graduate. What about someone who is not a student, but does have medical license (passed the USMLE tests), and is interested in doing a clinical rotation? I have noticed that hospitals list general information about rotations, but do not list them under their "career" open jobs. Any recommendations?

Comment: Will that be the same as internship, or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think externships may be helpful for your situation:

> [Externships](https://medclerkships.com/clinical-rotations/):
>   International Medical graduates looking to fulfill the “United States Clinical Experience” (USCE) requirements as necessitated by several residency programs.  Externships also provide doctors of international countries the opportunity for acclimatization with the US healthcare system. Doctors looking to familiarize themselves with Electronic Medical Records, Electronic Healthcare Record services, Medical Billing and Coding procedures, Insurance claims, and review of malpractice cases.  Externships are also a good way to have RECENT exposure to clinical patient care as many international applicants have been out of touch with patient care for many years prior.